# Multi-variable Epsilon Delta Proof of continuous Function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy + y$.  Give an epsilon-delta proof that the $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)} f(x,y)=3.$$

I know that $|x-1| < \delta$ and that $|y-1| < \delta$.  As well as $|xy|< (x^2 + y^2)/2$.

I start by trying to simplify $|x^2 + xy + y -3|$ in a way that makes $|y-1|$ and $|x-1|$ appear but I'm having a real difficulty.

Any help or hints with this solution would be greatly appreciated, it's been driving me nuts.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I edited your question to format it with Latex. I was a little confused as to what to do with $1/2(x^2 + y^2)$. Order of operations dictates that this is $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}$, but often people mean $\frac{1}{2(x^2 + y^2)}$. Can you clarify which one you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes find it's easier to shift the problem back to $(0, 0)$. If we let
\begin{align*}
u &= x - 1 \\
v &= y - 1
\end{align*}
then substituting back into the function minus $3$ yields,
$$(u + 1)^2 + (u + 1)(v + 1) + v + 1 - 3.$$
Expanding this expression yields,
$$u^2 + uv + 3u + 2v.$$
We could try bounding $|u|$ and $|v|$ by $\delta$ from here, but we could also back-substitute $x$ and $y$:
$$(x - 1)^2 + (x - 1)(y - 1) + 3(x - 1) + 2(y - 1).$$
Now you should be able to force each factor under $\varepsilon / 4$ by choosing an approrpiate $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you very much that really helped.  I think now by bounding delta to be less than or equal to one i can prove the limit by choosing  delta =min{1,epsilon/7}